# How to group data and store them in a new list by group

Tags: c#, linq

How can you store the data in the list by group?

Say,

```
public class ProductPrice
{
  public string Name { get; set }
  public decimal Price { get; set; }
  // Date and other properties
}
```

then having a record like this:

```
+--------+--------+
| Name   | Price  |
+--------+--------+
| Chair  | 11     |
| Table  | 15     |
| Table  | 30     |
| Window | 24     |
| Chair  | 29     |
+--------+--------+
```

What should be done in order to achieve a list something like this:

```
{
  {
    new ProductPrice { Name = "Chair", Price = 11 },
    new ProductPrice { Name = "Chair", Price = 29 },
  },
  {
    new ProductPrice { Name = "Table", Price = 15 },
    new ProductPrice { Name = "Table", Price = 30 }
  },
  {
    new ProductPrice { Name = "Window", Price = 24 }
  }
}
```

As you can see, they are grouped by their `Name` and store them in a list per group. It would be great to feed them to a, say, line chart to see their price trends. It's just that I am having hard time creating the list.

In a nutshell, can I create a `List` that is grouped by Products Name? Also, products can have new record as well?

Comment: looks like you need `List<List<ProductPrice>>` ???

Comment: Hi Mate. Think you can show me how? It would be great for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a `List<List<ProductPrice>>`, you can do:

```
List<List<ProductPrice>> groupedList = list.GroupBy(r => r.Name)
                    .Select(grp => new
                            {
                                List = grp.Select(r => r).ToList()
                            })
                    .Select(r => r.List)
                    .ToList();
```

This will return you three values in your `List` one for each group.

You can also project your results to `Dictionary<string, List<ProductPrice>>`, where your `key` would be the name of Product and value will contain `List<ProductPrice>` related to Key. Use [Enumerable.ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549277(v=vs.100).aspx) like:

```
Dictionary<string, List<ProductPrice>> groupedList = list.GroupBy(r => r.Name)
                        .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());
```

Comment: Hey! Wow! You just saved my life! Thank you so much. And for the use of `Dictionary`. Think you can explain what you did? For others to read in the future :)

Comment: @BoyPasmo, It is using [Enumerable.ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549277(v=vs.100).aspx) , I added a link, but I think It is simple to understand.